# Getting only the child elements of the first element

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My XML file is such as (for example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<bikes>
    <bike>
        <model>First</model>
        <speedNumber>4</speedNumber>
        <sizes>100</sizes>
        <amount>100</amount>
    </bike>
    <bike>
        <model>Second</model>
        <speedNumber>3</speedNumber>
        <sizes>300</sizes>
        <amount>150</amount>
    </bike>
    <bike>
        <model>Third</model>
        <speedNumber>4</speedNumber>
        <sizes>300</sizes>
        <amount>300</amount>
    </bike>
</bikes>
```

How can I get child elements for the first `<bike>` element only?
I want to print `model=First`, `speedNumber=4` ...

```
<bike>
  <model>First</model>
  <speedNumber>4</speedNumber>
  <sizes>100</sizes>
  <amount>100</amount>
</bike>
```

I tried this:

```
foreach ($xml->children(0) as $bikes) 
{
  foreach ($bikes->children() as $childs)
  {
    echo $childs->getName()."=".$childs ." ";
  }
  echo "<br>";
}
```

But it doesn't work for me.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could just access iterate over the `bike` elements and then break after the first one, https://eval.in/742822. Note your XML structure currently is invalid. You need to close the `bikes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the elements directly using array syntax:

```
$bikes->bike[0]->model
$bikes->bike[0]->speedNumber
...
```

Full code:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<bikes>
    <bike>
        <model>First</model>
        <speedNumber>4</speedNumber>
        <sizes>100</sizes>
        <amount>100</amount>
    </bike>
    <bike>
        <model>Second</model>
        <speedNumber>3</speedNumber>
        <sizes>300</sizes>
        <amount>150</amount>
    </bike>
    <bike>
        <model>Third</model>
        <speedNumber>4</speedNumber>
        <sizes>300</sizes>
        <amount>300</amount>
    </bike>
</bikes>
XML;

$bikes = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

echo $bikes->bike[0]->model . "\n";
echo $bikes->bike[0]->speedNumber . "\n";
echo $bikes->bike[0]->sizes . "\n";
echo $bikes->bike[0]->amount . "\n";

?>
```

Tested here: http://codepad.org/yVAyoPtG